# How do I detect an aborted connection in Django?

Tags: django, apache, http, wsgi

I have a Django view that does some pretty heavy processing and takes around 20-30 seconds to return a result.

Sometimes the user will end up closing the browser window (terminating the connection) before the request completes -- in that case, I'd like to be able to detect this and stop working.  The work I do is read-only on the database so there isn't any issue with transactions.

In PHP the [connection_aborted](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php) function does exactly this.  Is this functionality available in Django?

Here's example code I'd like to write:

```
def myview(request):
    while not connection_aborted():
        # do another bit of work...
        if work_complete:
            return HttpResponse('results go here')
```

Thanks.

Comment: People tend not to be tolerant of long wait times with a blank screen. I'd suggest that you return a page that will render request this heavy lifting with AJAX, possibly with a progress spinner...

Comment: I agree completely -- this view is in fact called by AJAX while rendering a progress spinner and a message that it could take a while for the user.

Comment: @MattH: that doesn't solve OP's problem though.  Even if it's implemented through AJAX, the user can move to another URL and abort the connection, then OP still needs to detect it.

Comment: @André, which is why it was a comment/suggestion, rather than a "solution".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Django provides it because it basically can't.  More than Django itself, this depends on the way Django interfaces with your web server.  All this depends on your software stack (which you have not specified).  I don't think it's even part of the FastCGI and WSGI protocols!

**Edit**: I'm also pretty sure that Django does not start sending *any* data to the client until your view finishes execution, so it can't possibly know if the connection is dead. The underlying socket won't trigger an error unless the server tries to send some data back to the user.

Answer (score 0):

That `connection_aborted` method in PHP doesn't do what you think it does. It will tell you if the client disconnected *but* only if the buffer has been flushed, i.e. some sort of response is sent from the server back to the client. The PHP versions wouldn't even work as you've written if above. You'd have to add a call to something like `flush` within your loop to have the server attempt to send data.

HTTP is a stateless protocol. It's *designed* to not have either the client or the server dependent on each other. As a result the state of either is only known when there is a connection is created, and that only occurs when there's some data to send one way or another.

Your best bet is to do as @MattH suggested and do this through a bit of AJAX, and if you'd like you can integrate something like Node.js to make client "check-ins" during processing. How to set that up properly is beyond my area of expertise, though.

Comment: HTTP is stateless between HTTP requests.  The connection itself obviously has (maybe implicit) state such as "how many bytes the server has received from the client.

Comment: The connection may store some data between requests, but it doesn't matter. Bytes received from client, to use your example, would not change unless some communication is opened between the server and the client. If the client is waiting for the server to respond (not sending data) and the server is processing the request (not sending data), the connection has no state.

Answer (score -1):

So you have an AJAX view that runs a query that takes 20-30 seconds to process requested in the background of a rendered page and you're concerned about wasted resources for when someone cancels the page load.

I see that you've got options in three broad categories:

1. Live with it. Improve the situation by caching the results in case the user comes back.
2. Make it faster. Throw more space at a time/space trade-off. Maintain intermediate tables. Precalculate the entire thing, etc.
3. Do something clever with the browser fast-polling a "is it ready yet?" query and the server cancelling the query if it doesn't receive a nag within interval * 2 or similar. If you're really clever, you could return progress / ETA to the nags. However, this might not have particularly useful behaviour when the system is under load or your site is being accessed over limited bandwidth.

I don't think you should go for option 3 because it's increasing complexity and resource usage for not much gain.